# How to rename composer vendor install path?

Tags: php, yii, composer-php

Thats my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
"description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true,
"repositories": {
    "Leopandro": {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "Leopandro/yii2-user",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/Leopandro/yii2-user",
                "type": "git",
                "reference":"dd41fccbab926f3719a378ddd698e7976f57eca5"
            }
        }
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "Leopandro/yii2-user": "dev-master",
    "execut/yii2-widget-bootstraptreeview": "dev-master",
    "2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget": "~1.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
    "paulzi/yii2-adjacency-list": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Leopandro": "vendor/Leopandro/yii2-user/"
    }
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
        "setPermission": [
            {
                "runtime": "0777",
                "web/assets": "0777",
                "yii": "0755"
            }
        ],
        "generateCookieValidationKey": [
            "config/web.php"
        ]
    },
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

}

My package "`Leopandro/yii2-user`" installs into "`vendor/Leopandro/yii2-soft`". I want to change folder name into "`vendor/dektrium/yii2-soft`" becouse my package depends on folder name :(

Comment: Don't depend on folder names!

Answer (score 0):

There is a package [composer/installers](https://github.com/composer/installers) which has to be required by your package `Leopandro/yii2-user`. Then the consuming project is able to change the vendor install path:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "sites/example.com/modules/{$name}": ["vendor/package"]
        }
    }
}
```

For detailed information see [Composer Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md).

Info: Be careful with changing such things as they are usually not meant to be changed and can result in conflicts with other packages.